# How to configure GlassFish JavaMail to use Amazon SES?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, glassfish-3, amazon-ses

I have not found any clear documentation on configuring GlassFish's JavaMail to use Amazon SES to send out email messages. Could someone please provide an example?

Comment: Amazon SES supports SMTP [since December 2011](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/new-smtp-support-for-the-simple-email-service-ses.html). Seems like that is as easy as it gets?

Answer (score 3):

Inside the [AWS JDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) you can find a sample in: samples\AmazonSimpleEmailService\AWSJavaMailSample.java

Basically, you need to set the protocol to "aws", and the user and password to your AWS credentials:

```
/*
 * Setup JavaMail to use the Amazon Simple Email Service by specifying
 * the "aws" protocol.
 */
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "aws");

/*
 * Setting mail.aws.user and mail.aws.password are optional. Setting
 * these will allow you to send mail using the static transport send()
 * convince method.  It will also allow you to call connect() with no
 * parameters. Otherwise, a user name and password must be specified
 * in connect.
 */
props.setProperty("mail.aws.user", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
props.setProperty("mail.aws.password", credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
```

In order to send the message:

```
// Create a email session
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

// Create a new Message
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
msg.setText(BODY);
msg.saveChanges();

// Reuse one Transport object for sending all your messages
// for better performance
Transport t = new AWSJavaMailTransport(session, null);
t.connect();
t.sendMessage(msg, null);
```

That should do the job for you.

Comment: Do you know of any reason not to use [Amazon SES's SMTP interface](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.html) instead? (As [announced](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/new-smtp-support-for-the-simple-email-service-ses.html) in December 2011.)

Answer (score 2):

You can have Glassfish provide the JavaMail session allowing your application code to be provider agnostic.

Create a JavaMail Session using the Glassfish Admin interface:

Resources->JavaMail Sessions.

The key attributes are:

- **JNDI**: mail/somevalue
- **Mail Host**: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- **Default Sender Address**: Source email address
- **Transport Protocol**: aws
- **Transport Protocol Class**: com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport

The form also requires a values for "Default User" but from what I can tell, it won't be used.

In addition, you need to add the following properties to the session:

- **mail.aws.password**: your AWS Secret Key
- **mail.aws.user**: your AWS Access Key

Your application code can obtain the Session via injection:

```
@Resource(name="mail/somevalue")
private Session mailSession;
```

To send an email using the injected session

```
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    try {
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(body);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
        msg.setFrom();

        Transport t = session.getTransport();

        if (!t.isConnected()) {
            t.connect();
        }

        t.sendMessage(msg, null);

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        // Handle exception
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        // Handle exception         
    }
```

The call to **msg.setFrom()** will populate the From field of the message with the value held in the session property "mail.user", which is taken from the JavaMail Session field "Default Senders Address"